# Can I input a month on a spreadsheet so that it pre-populates total working days and working days passed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calendar, report

I want to be able to input the month I am reporting on (circled red) and it pre-populates the total amount of working days, Mon - Fri (circled yellow)

Then I want to be able to input the previous working day date (circled green) - and it will change how many working days have passed up to that date (circled blue)

[image: My report I work off]

I hope this all makes sense to you guys.

I have tried working off a date picker so far but I don't believe that works. I think I need to go off a calendar data source but I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

###### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

I made some modifications to my replication since no data was provided in your question in order to accomplish what you'd like based on the screenshot provided. I also used the `=DATE()`, `=EOMONTH()`, and `=NETWORKDAYS()` functions that are available in Microsoft Excel.

###### EXPLANATION

You will be putting two values in the output I've performed. `A1`, where it would be equal to the month you have mentioned and the last business day on cell `B4`.

`A2` cell would have the value `=DATE(B1,A1,1)`, where `B1` is equal to `2023`, the year you'll put, `A1` is equal to what I mentioned above, and `1`, which is the starting point of every month.

`C4` cell has `=NETWORKDAYS(A2, B4, 0)`, which would have `A2`, `B4`, the last business day you'll input as mentioned above, and `0`, an optional value.

`F4` cell has `=C4/G4`, which is a simple division of the month you'll put and the actual working days of the month.

`G4` cell has `=NETWORKDAYS(A2, C1, 0)`, which would have the start dates of `A2`, `C1`, and `0`.

`H4`, which is the last cell, is divided by itself so that it would always be `100%` of the actual number of working days for the month.

> *Note: The reason why `A1` is the place where you'll be putting your month is so that the output in the screenshot can be achieved. Also, make sure that your formats for the dates and percentage are correct to get what you'd like.*

###### OUTPUT

[image: Click Here]

###### REFERENCES

- [DATE function](https://support.microsoft.com/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349)
- [EOMONTH function](https://support.microsoft.com/office/eomonth-function-7314ffa1-2bc9-4005-9d66-f49db127d628)
- [NETWORKDAYS function](https://support.microsoft.com/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7)